# fdisk or sfdisk + how to show the disks size in GIB and not in GB

Tags: fdisk, lsblk, sfdisk

we can print all disks by the following ( on our RHEL machine )

```
fdisk -lu | grep "Disk /dev"
Disk /dev/sda: 247.0 GB, 246960619520 bytes, 482344960 sectors
Disk /dev/sdb: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Disk /dev/sdc: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Disk /dev/sdd: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Disk /dev/sde: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
```

as we can see above disks are in GB and not in GIB

note:

GB is the traditional, metric style of measurement with 1 GB equaling 1,000³ bytes.

GiB is the binary method; which is the way computers measure data at 1024³ bytes.

any option by using fdisk or sfdisk or maybe other manipulation in order to print the disks size with GIB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `fdisk` man page:

> In the case the size is specified in bytes than the number may be followed by the multiplicative suffixes KiB=1024, MiB=1024*1024, and so on for GiB, TiB, PiB, EiB, ZiB and YiB. The "iB" is optional, e.g., "K" has the same meaning as "KiB".
> For backward compatibility fdisk also accepts the suffixes KB=1000, MB=1000*1000, and so on for GB, TB, PB, EB, ZB and YB. These 10^N suffixes are **deprecated**.

IOW, you'll need to patch it and it doesn't sound likely that your patch will ever be accepted/merged.

Here's the obvious rationale behind it: all modern storage devices operate with either 512 or 4096 bytes sectors - the latter becoming more and more ubiquitous. `1MB` is **not** even divisible by either 512 or 4096.